# Want to get count and cityname for all the rows in a table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Any other process to get all the count with the distinct values from a table in cassandra like a group function in MySQL or Oracle

Example following is a table with cities:

> cityid cityname
>   1      Lucknow
>   1      Lucknow
>   3      Delhi
>   4      Noida
>   5      Agra
>   5      Agra
>   5      Agra

I want the following output produced in cassandra:

> count  Cityname
>    2    Lucknow
>    1    Noida
>    1    Delhi
>    3    Agra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function count(*) does not exist in cassandra. Alternativelly you can use counter https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html.

```
create table cities(
   cityname text,
   count counter,
PRIMARY KEY(cityname)
);
```

For updating the table use:

```
  UPDATE cities SET count = count + 1 WHERE cityname ='Lucknow';
```